# What is this group that applies transforms onto objects?

Tags: import, transforms, .fbx, optimization

I downloaded an asset kit which when imported into blender places objects inside some sort of group (screenshots below). On their own objects have incorrect size and rotation, but when placed within this group, they appear as they should.

I want to cleanup this asset kit and remove these "transform" groups so I am just left with my objects, I can do this, but it seems like very manual work (I need to delete transform group and then manually apply its changes onto an object). Perhaps there is an easier way?

So, this is how it looks in outliner, group I am asking about is one with icon that has 3 branches

[image]

This is transform that this group has, which actually makes object look correct

[image]

And this is transform that object itself has

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an Empty, you could parent objects to that empty and that will become the new world zero for the object. Your object has keyframes (that's why is green) and probably that's the reason for the "incorrect size"

[image]